# marker-based image segmentation suggestions

Tags: opencv, image-processing, watershed

I am trying to do biomedical image segmentation via topological data analysis which is mainly my research area. I started with the image on the left, applied TDA and obtained the numpy array with 4 channels on the right which pretty much fully represents the neuron boundaries of the original image..

Now, my goal is ideally enumerate these regions of interests, and reach out the contour surrounding each neuron by calling the index of that contour.

I tried `cv2.findContours` but as you can see some regions are just intercellular gaps and doesn't correspond to actual cells.

`cv2.watershed` might work but I don't know exactly how to use a markerbased watershed algorithm since image processing is not my area...

original and aggregated images

[image: original and aggregated images]

The marker image I obtained with TDA is actually the sum of small markers, so I could have used each of these small images to feed in the `findContours` but they are even more noisy then the original image so I don't even bother and trying to find my way out using the aggregated marker image above

small markers

[image: small markers]

I am open to suggestions..